# Elements appended to SVG with D3 are not appearing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to display some simple bar charts with D3 where each bar is a `div`, but nothing is being displayed.

```js
var chartData =  [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
var body = d3.select('body');
     
var svg = body.append('svg')
   .attr("width",800)
   .attr("height",500);
        
var div = svg.append('div').attr('class', '.chart');
     
for (var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
   div.append('div')
     .attr("height", 20)
     .attr("width", chartData[i]*10)
     .html(chartData[i]);
}
```

```css
.chart div {
 font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
 text-align: right;
 padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

When using inspecting the SVG I see the newly created elements and the svg is highlighted but the inner `div`s are not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a nutshell: you **cannot** append a HTML element to a SVG. The reason is simple: `<div>`, `<p>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<td>`, `<li>` and so on are not valid SVG elements.

This has been asked and answered many, many times. However, I'd like to answer this question because of a specific part of it (which is normally not asked):

> When using chrome's inspect I see the newly created elements.

Yes, the elements are there. But this doesn't mean it's going to work.

Let's show this in the following snippet, in which I'm appending `<div>`s to the SVG. look at the `console.log`, it shows the SVG structure:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = d3.range(5);

var divs = svg.selectAll("foo")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("div")
 .html("Where are you?")
 
var mySVG = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg.node());
console.log(mySVG)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

You can see that the divs are in the DOM. However, there is nothing on the screen...

The fact that you see the element in the DOM means nothing, because you can append **anything**!

For instance, let's append an element named `CharlesDarwin`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = d3.range(5);

var divs = svg.selectAll("foo")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("CharlesDarwin")
 .html("I'm a strange tag!")
 
var mySVG = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg.node());
console.log(mySVG)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

You can see `<charlesDarwin>` in the DOM. However, it's obvious that nothing will show up in the SVG.

**PS**: Regarding your chart:

1. Get rid of that for loop. You don't need that when using D3;
2. Set the class **without** the dot;
3. Append the divs to the body, as discussed above.

This is the working code:

```js
var chartData = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var body = d3.select('body');

var div = body.selectAll("foo")
  .data(chartData)
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'chart')
  .style("width", d => d * 10 + "px")
  .html(d => d);
```

```css
.chart {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good answer, but you haven't really explained *why* it won't work. The reason is because `<div>` is not a valid SVG element.  So has no effect inside an `<svg>`.

Comment: Indeed, @PaulLeBeau, you're right! As I already explained that in the previous dozens of times a similar question has been asked, I forgot to repeat the explanation in this one. Edited.

Comment: Thank you Gerardo. For the through explanation. I learned something new from your response. Thanks.

Comment: I have coppied and pasted your code into index.html, app.js, and app.css and still I see nothing. I am very confused about how to get this to work.

Comment: I can't see anything either - was that your settings?

Comment: @qwerty What do you mean by *"I can't see anything"*? Just click "Run code snippet".

Comment: I can see the snippet correctly, but when I copied and pasted it into own file, I couldn't see anything. I managed to fix it - turned out I added the path to my js file at the top :facepalm: